# Will it be unethical to ask the author of a published work to share their code?

Tags: publications, research-process, ethics

I have been working on reproducing the implementation of a model described in a published paper. The paper was published in 2007. I have been trying for quite some time, but I am unable to make any significant progress. Can I contact the corresponding author of the paper asking them to share the code for use in my research? After I understand the implementation, I intend to modify the model based on my own research work. Will it be unethical or rude to ask the authors this directly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I request the code behind a research paper from the author?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/26159/can-i-request-the-code-behind-a-research-paper-from-the-author)

Comment: It is certainly ok to ask.  In my opinion, it is obligatory to ask so you can avoid wasteful duplication.

Comment: There may be many reasons the authors no longer have the code (hard disk failure etc). Perhaps you should consider writing the code yourself.

Comment: I think ethics only comes into play, if the contacted author actually shares the code. I am struggling to imagine how to ask unethical questions in academic research. Maybe I am just unimaginative.